# More RAM used than shown in top

Tags: java, top

I got a weird problem at top. My RAM-Usage is at ~25GB but the Resident-Memory of all my processes added together is about 15GB.

```
top - 11:31:27 up 30 days, 21:43,  1 user,  load average: 4.08, 4.11, 4.06
Tasks: 210 total,   1 running, 209 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 25.3 us,  1.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 62.3 id, 10.8 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:  32875980 total, 24213416 used,  8662564 free,   816628 buffers
KiB Swap: 15992828 total,    31348 used, 15961480 free.  8235816 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
19863 minecra+  20   0 6356164 702236  19868 S  97.2  2.1   0:42.03 java
26621 minecra+  20   0 9403048 2.307g  20440 S  39.6  7.4 264:38.71 java
26498 minecra+  20   0 10.007g 2.505g  20536 S  21.3  8.0 128:37.44 java
 9598 minecra+  20   0 9022864 685984  21764 S  11.6  2.1   4:44.81 java
26243 minecra+  20   0 13.777g 1.578g  19536 S   8.7  5.0  47:00.63 java
26810 minecra+  20   0 10.009g 2.332g  20568 S   8.3  7.4 425:14.58 java
 8268 mysql     20   0 1151044 359732  14572 S   8.0  1.1  59:23.15 mysqld
19826 minecra+  20   0 6358212 740572  19912 S   7.0  2.3   0:56.78 java
 6122 teamspe+  20   0 1220216  32472   5936 S   3.7  0.1   1775:55 ts3server
20993 minecra+  20   0 6353896 647896  19856 S   3.0  2.0   0:28.94 java
32633 minecra+  20   0 6364144 704768  19880 S   3.0  2.1  64:46.45 java
 3075 minecra+  20   0 6363124 686680  19996 S   2.7  2.1  39:20.96 java
13456 minecra+  20   0 6356964 653664  19840 S   2.7  2.0   1:25.49 java
21451 web       20   0  372464  38164  27208 S   1.0  0.1   0:00.56 php5-fpm
```

I'm wondering where the other 10GB are, is the RES-Memory not the right indicator for the memory?

Comment: Look into [htop](https://hisham.hm/htop/).

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: I/O (including but not limited to disk) buffers.

Longer answer: go read http://linuxatemyram.com